# How do I avoid visual bug when navigating from one screen to another? - React Native Expo

Tags: node.js, reactjs, iphone, react-native, expo

I'm creating a sign in screen and a create account screen on my application. I have buttons that go back and forth to each other. Both screens work fine individually.  When I do this, there can often be a visual error like so:

My App.js Code:

```
const App = () => {

  return (
    <NavigationContainer theme={theme}>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false}} initialRouteName="CreateAccountScreen">
        <Stack.Screen name ="CreateAccountScreen" component={CreateAccountScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name ="SignInScreen" component={ SignInScreen } />
      </Stack.Navigator> 
     </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Code from each Screens button that goes back and forth:

```
onSignUpButtonPressed = () => {
    navigation.navigate("SignInScreen")
}

onCreateAccountButtonPressed = () => {
    navigation.navigate("CreateAccountScreen")
}
```

[Displays seem to overlay themselves in a bad way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrSiU.jpg)

I've tried a bunch of things and this has happened on several screens...

Comment: Are you swapping in a rapid-fire type manner? Or every few seconds?

Comment: @Bellarose143 it happens the first time I do the transition, and I’m not doing it fast at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your `initialRouteName` is set up as we can see but on your `Stack.Screen` you also give it the Component attribute.

I did a test based on how my navigation looks and I did not get the visual bug you showed so I think if you removed the component attribute and maybe just put the component tag inside your `Stack.Screen` as shown below it might work. Just imagine my `Home` is your `CreateAccountScreen`.

```
<Stack.Navigator
    initialRouteName='Home'
>
<Stack.Screen
    name="Home"
    options={{
       headerShown: false,
    }}
>
    {props => <Home {...props} username='Bella' />}
</Stack.Screen>
```

You also dont have the code in your question to define `Stack` like this:

`const Stack = createStackNavigator();`